# Math.trunc issue or incorrect usage

Tags: javascript

I have a Formula to convert DMS GPS co-ordinates to Decimal degrees,

however I tried to wright it in JS but not Working,

during testing i noticed that the Values of 'latlng' is correctly being Split but once i try using Math.trunc it just stops providing data

here is the Function:

```
function convertdec() {
var input1 = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
var latlongc = input1.split( ',' ,2);
var latdeg1 = Math.trunc(parseInt(latlngc[0])); 
var latmin1 = Math.trunc((parseInt(latlngc[0])-latdeg1)*60); 
var latsec1 = (((parseInt(latlngc[0])-latdeg1)*60)-latmin1)*60; 
var longdeg1 = Math.trunc(parseInt(latlngc[1]));
var longmin1 = Math.trunc((parseInt(latlngc[1])-longdeg1)*60);
var longsec1 = (((parseInt(latlngc[0])-latdeg1)*60)-longmin1)*60;

document.getElementById('deg1').value = latdeg1;
document.getElementById('min1').value = latmin1;
document.getElementById('sec1').value = latsec1;
document.getElementById('deg2').value = longdeg1;
document.getElementById('min2').value = longmin1;
document.getElementById('sec2').value = longsec1;

}
```

the layout is correct for the formula however apparently not for the Script

Please assist in explaining what i am doing wrong

Comment: `Math.trunc()` is part of the proposed ECMA 6 and not supported in all browsers.  You should check your browser error console or debug console to see if `Math.trunc()` does not exist and is causing your issue.  You can look at `Math.floor()` for an alternative (depending upon exactly what you're trying to do).

Comment: found a problem, var latlongc should be latlngc

Comment: Why are you trying to truncate integers anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
    function convertdec() {
var input1 = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
var latlngc = input1.split( ',' ,2);
var latdeg1 = Math.floor(parseInt(latlngc[0])); 
var latmin01 = (latlngc[0]-latdeg1)*60; 
var latmin1 = Math.floor(latmin01); 
var latsec01 = (latmin01-latmin1); 
var latsec1 = latsec01*60; 
var longdeg1 = Math.floor(parseInt(latlngc[1]));
var longmin01 = (latlngc[1]-longdeg1)*60;
var longmin1 = Math.floor(longmin01); 
var longsec01 = (longmin01-longmin1)
var longsec1 = longsec01*60


document.getElementById('deg1').value = latdeg1;
document.getElementById('min1').value = latmin1;
document.getElementById('sec1').value = latsec1; 
document.getElementById('deg2').value = longdeg1;
document.getElementById('min2').value = longmin1;
document.getElementById('sec2').value = longsec1;

}
```